# Showing that $f(x)=e^{x-5}-\ln(x-4)-1$ has only one real root

Tags: calculus, functions, roots

There is a simple problem. I need to prove that there is just one $x$ such that $f(x)=0$.

$$f(x)=e^{x-5}-\ln(x-4)-1$$

I realized that $f(5)=0$ but how can I prove that it is the only one?

Comment: Based on the graph of the function, I'd say you should take the derivative, show it is zero at $x=5$, and show $f(5) = 0$ too. Then show that the function is positive and always decreasing to the left of $x=5$, and positive and always increasing to the right of there.

Comment: If you suppose that it has a second $x$-value where $f(x)=0$, what theorem could you then apply to this function that may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}:$ Use second derivative test to show $x=5$ is a global  $\textit{minimum}$.

Comment: Based on the graph, $x=5$ would be at a global *minimum*, not maximum.

Comment: Oops typo. Thanks